# Как нарисовать окружность поверх рабочего стола с мягкими краями?

Tags: windows, delphi

Как избавится от артефактов на краях круга. Круг это WinControl у которого

```
Window.setparent(handle,0)
```

Круг c прозрачностью  `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`

Рисование с помощью

`Graphics := TGPGraphics.Create(ACanvas.Handle);`

Причем если WinControl закрасить `FillRect` то артефактов нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тебе хочется с антиалиасингом? Универсальный совет - сделать через png с прозрачностью (тогда какую прозрачность сделаешь, так и будет выглядеть). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422237/how-to-draw-transparent-with-alpha-transparency-in-delphi

Comment: @VladChapl вы ссылаетесь на рисование на Canvas - это немного другое. PNG тут тоже не в тему как-то - это же всего лишь контейнер для RGBA.